# PHP - edit initialised singleton object

Tags: php, class, singleton

I have this class,

```
class Player {

    protected static $volume;
    protected static $instance = null;

    protected function __construct()
    {
        self::$volume = 5;
        $this->maxVolume = 20;
    }

    protected function __clone() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(static::$instance)) {
            static::$instance = new static;
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }


    public function volumeUp() {
        if (self::$volume < $this->maxVolume) {
            self::$volume = self::$volume + 1;
        }

        return static::$volume;
    }

    public function volumeDown () {
        if (self::$volume > 0) {
            self::$volume = self::$volume - 1;
        }

        return static::$volume;
    }
}
```

I wanted to change object values dynamically by calling the method volumeUp or volumeDown.

```
$player = \Player\Player::getInstance();

 if (isset($data['volume']) && isset($data['down'])) {

        echo $player->volumeDown();
    }

    if (isset($data['volume']) && isset($data['up'])) {
        echo $player->volumeUp();
    }
```

When I call those methods object act like new instance and gives me always the same result.

Where I make wrong move?

Comment: You use various $volume in the methods body and in return statment.

Comment: Are you calling it by separate requests? If yes, then there is nothing around static variables... store them at list in session

Comment: @FieryCat Yes, I call it by separate requests via ajax. I will try now with the session.